# freeglut (./light): ERROR: Internal error <FBConfig with necessary capabilities not found> in function fgOpenWindow

Tags: opengl, x11, glut, freeglut

I installed the OpenGL in Linux server (Ubuntu16.04) without a graphical interface, install command below:

```
apt-get install build-essential libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev
apt-get install freeglut3-dev libglew1.10 libglew-dev libgl1-mesa-glx libxmu-dev
apt-get install libglew-dev libsdl2-dev libsdl2-image-dev libglm-dev libfreetype6-dev
apt-get install mesa-utils
```

now, I compile `light.c` by `gcc light.c -o light -lGL -lglut`.

**I want to display it in my Windows mechine by XMing server.**

code:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void init ( void )
{
    GLfloat mat_specular [ ] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
    GLfloat mat_shininess [ ] = { 50.0 };
    GLfloat light_position [ ] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0 };
    glClearColor ( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
    glShadeModel ( GL_SMOOTH );
    glMaterialfv ( GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, mat_specular);
    glMaterialfv ( GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, mat_shininess);
    glLightfv ( GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position);
    glEnable (GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable (GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable (GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}
void display ( void )
{
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glutSolidSphere (1.0, 40, 50);
    glFlush ();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit (&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize (300, 300);
    glutInitWindowPosition (100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow ( argv [ 0 ] );
    init ( );
    glutDisplayFunc ( display );
    glutMainLoop( );
    return 0;
}
```

but, I get a error:

```
freeglut (./light):  ERROR:  Internal error <FBConfig with necessary capabilities not found> in function fgOpenWindow
```

I search this problem in google, and find some method, but they are not available.

`glxinfo` is good.

```
name of display: :10.0
display: :10  screen: 0
direct rendering: No (LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT set)
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.2
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_visual_info, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_SGIS_multisample, 
    GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_hyperpipe, GLX_SGIX_swap_barrier, 
    GLX_SGI_make_current_read
client glx vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_context_flush_control, GLX_ARB_create_context, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, 
    GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, 
    GLX_EXT_buffer_age, GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, 
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile, GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, 
    GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_stereo_tree, 
    GLX_EXT_swap_control, GLX_EXT_swap_control_tear, 
    GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, 
    GLX_NV_copy_buffer, GLX_NV_copy_image, GLX_NV_delay_before_swap, 
    GLX_NV_float_buffer, GLX_NV_multisample_coverage, GLX_NV_present_video, 
    GLX_NV_robustness_video_memory_purge, GLX_NV_swap_group, 
    GLX_NV_video_capture, GLX_NV_video_out, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, 
    GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync
GLX version: 1.2
GLX extensions:
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce GT 705/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL version string: 1.2 (4.5.0 NVIDIA 368.39)
OpenGL extensions:
    GL_ARB_depth_texture, GL_ARB_imaging, GL_ARB_multitexture, 
    GL_ARB_point_parameters, GL_ARB_point_sprite, GL_ARB_shadow, 
    GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp, GL_ARB_texture_cube_map, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_add, GL_ARB_texture_env_combine, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar, GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3, 
    GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat, GL_ARB_transpose_matrix, 
    GL_ARB_window_pos, GL_ATI_texture_mirror_once, GL_EXT_abgr, GL_EXT_bgra, 
    GL_EXT_blend_color, GL_EXT_blend_func_separate, GL_EXT_blend_minmax, 
    GL_EXT_blend_subtract, GL_EXT_draw_range_elements, GL_EXT_fog_coord, 
    GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays, GL_EXT_packed_pixels, GL_EXT_rescale_normal, 
    GL_EXT_secondary_color, GL_EXT_separate_specular_color, 
    GL_EXT_shadow_funcs, GL_EXT_stencil_two_side, GL_EXT_stencil_wrap, 
    GL_EXT_texture3D, GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp, GL_EXT_texture_env_add, 
    GL_EXT_texture_env_combine, GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3, GL_EXT_texture_lod, 
    GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias, GL_EXT_texture_object, GL_EXT_vertex_array, 
    GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat, GL_NV_blend_square, GL_NV_point_sprite, 
    GL_NV_texgen_reflection, GL_NV_texture_rectangle, GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap, 
    GL_SGIS_texture_lod, GL_SGIX_depth_texture, GL_SGIX_shadow

32 GLX Visuals
    visual  x   bf lv rg d st  colorbuffer  sr ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav
  id dep cl sp  sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a F gb bf th cl  r  g  b  a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x022 24 tc  1  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x023 24 tc  1  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x024 24 tc  1  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x025 24 tc  1  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x026 24 tc  1  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x027 24 tc  1  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x028 24 tc  1  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x029 24 tc  1  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  8 16 16 16 16 1172601720 0 None
0x02a 24 tc  1  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  1 4 None
0x02b 24 tc  1  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  2  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x02c 24 tc  1  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  2  0  8  0  0  0  0 26272464 0 None
0x02d 24 tc  1  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  2  0  8 16 16 16 16 26259104 0 None
0x02e 24 tc  1  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x02f 24 tc  1  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  2  0  0 16 16 16 16 32 0 None
0x030 24 tc  1  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  2  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x031 24 tc  1  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  2  0  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x032 24 tc  1  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x033 24 tc  1  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x034 24 tc  1  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0 26262256 1 None
0x035 24 tc  1  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16 26259056 0 None
0x036 24 tc  1  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x037 24 tc  1  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x038 24 tc  1  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x039 24 tc  1  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x03a 24 tc  1  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  2 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x03b 24 tc  1  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  2 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x03c 24 tc  1  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  2 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x03d 24 tc  1  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  2 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x03e 24 tc  1  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  2 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x03f 24 tc  1  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  2 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x040 24 tc  1  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  2 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x041 24 tc  1  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  2 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None

32 GLXFBConfigs:
    visual  x   bf lv rg d st  colorbuffer  sr ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav
  id dep cl sp  sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a F gb bf th cl  r  g  b  a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x022 24 tc  1  24  0    . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x023 24 tc  1  24  0    . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x024 24 tc  1  24  0    . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x025 24 tc  1  24  0    . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x026 24 tc  1  24  0    y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x027 24 tc  1  24  0    y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x028 24 tc  1  24  0    y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x029 24 tc  1  24  0    y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x02a 24 tc  1  24  0    . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x02b 24 tc  1  24  0    . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  2  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x02c 24 tc  1  24  0    . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  2  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x02d 24 tc  1  24  0    . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  2  0  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x02e 24 tc  1  24  0    y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x02f 24 tc  1  24  0    y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  2  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x030 24 tc  1  24  0    y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  2  0  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x031 24 tc  1  24  0    y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  2  0  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x032 24 tc  1  24  0    . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x033 24 tc  1  24  0    . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x034 24 tc  1  24  0    . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x035 24 tc  1  24  0    . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x036 24 tc  1  24  0    y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x037 24 tc  1  24  0    y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x038 24 tc  1  24  0    y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x039 24 tc  1  24  0    y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x03a 24 tc  1  24  0    . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  2 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x03b 24 tc  1  24  0    . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  2 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x03c 24 tc  1  24  0    . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  2 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x03d 24 tc  1  24  0    . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  2 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x03e 24 tc  1  24  0    y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  2 24  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x03f 24 tc  1  24  0    y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  2 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x040 24 tc  1  24  0    y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  2 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x041 24 tc  1  24  0    y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  2 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
```

`glxdemo`,`glxgears`,`glxheads` are also good.

When I run the `Xlib` code, it is good. Compile is by `gcc -o quad quad.c -lX11 -lGL -lGLU`

```
// -- Written in C -- //

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<X11/X.h>
#include<X11/Xlib.h>
#include<GL/gl.h>
#include<GL/glx.h>
#include<GL/glu.h>

Display                 *dpy;
Window                  root;
GLint                   att[] = { GLX_RGBA, GLX_DEPTH_SIZE, 24, GLX_DOUBLEBUFFER, None };
XVisualInfo             *vi;
Colormap                cmap;
XSetWindowAttributes    swa;
Window                  win;
GLXContext              glc;
XWindowAttributes       gwa;
XEvent                  xev;

void DrawAQuad() {
 glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
 glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

 glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
 glLoadIdentity();
 glOrtho(-1., 1., -1., 1., 1., 20.);

 glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
 glLoadIdentity();
 gluLookAt(0., 0., 10., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.);

 glBegin(GL_QUADS);
  glColor3f(1., 0., 0.); glVertex3f(-.75, -.75, 0.);
  glColor3f(0., 1., 0.); glVertex3f( .75, -.75, 0.);
  glColor3f(0., 0., 1.); glVertex3f( .75,  .75, 0.);
  glColor3f(1., 1., 0.); glVertex3f(-.75,  .75, 0.);
 glEnd();
} 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

 dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL);

 if(dpy == NULL) {
        printf("\n\tcannot connect to X server\n\n");
        exit(0);
 }

 root = DefaultRootWindow(dpy);

 vi = glXChooseVisual(dpy, 0, att);

 if(vi == NULL) {
        printf("\n\tno appropriate visual found\n\n");
        exit(0);
 } 
 else {
        printf("\n\tvisual %p selected\n", (void *)vi->visualid); /* %p creates hexadecimal output like in glxinfo */
 }


 cmap = XCreateColormap(dpy, root, vi->visual, AllocNone);

 swa.colormap = cmap;
 swa.event_mask = ExposureMask | KeyPressMask;

 win = XCreateWindow(dpy, root, 0, 0, 600, 600, 0, vi->depth, InputOutput, vi->visual, CWColormap | CWEventMask, &swa);

 XMapWindow(dpy, win);
 XStoreName(dpy, win, "VERY SIMPLE APPLICATION");

 glc = glXCreateContext(dpy, vi, NULL, GL_TRUE);
 glXMakeCurrent(dpy, win, glc);

 glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); 

 while(1) {
        XNextEvent(dpy, &xev);

        if(xev.type == Expose) {
                XGetWindowAttributes(dpy, win, &gwa);
                glViewport(0, 0, gwa.width, gwa.height);
                DrawAQuad(); 
                glXSwapBuffers(dpy, win);
        }

        else if(xev.type == KeyPress) {
                glXMakeCurrent(dpy, None, NULL);
                glXDestroyContext(dpy, glc);
                XDestroyWindow(dpy, win);
                XCloseDisplay(dpy);
                exit(0);
        }
    } /* this closes while(1) { */
} /* this is the } which closes int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { */
```

What should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, your xlib code requests double-buffering while your GLUT code only wants single-buffering.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I change my code from `glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);` to `glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);`. But it is still wrong `freeglut (./light):  ERROR:  Internal error <FBConfig with necessary capabilities not found> in function fgOpenWindow`.

Comment: Try calling `glutInitDisplayMode(0)` instead of all these parameters and see what you get. Try also `glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_INDEX)`.

Answer (score 3):

```
direct rendering: No (LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT set)
```

Make sure you aren't running afoul of [this bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/freeglut/bugs/123/):

> 2.4.06 doesn't render on remote X server from ubuntu client.
>
> Ubuntu seems to be using freeglut now, and while it renders ok to the local display it fails to draw via GLX on a remote display. Maybe it doesn't get a valid context because glGetString(gl_version) returns null. However glutGet(GLUT_DISPLAY_MODE_POSSIBLE) returns true, and glxgears and glxinfo both work ok, so it appears to be a freeglut problem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I run the demo code but get a different result.   `GLUT_DISPLAYMODE_POSSIBLE = 0`
`freeglut (./test):  ERROR:  Internal error <FBConfig with necessary capabilities not found> in function fgOpenWindow`

Comment: thanks, this bug (X over ssh) was the case for me when running zed mini stereolabs demo for positional tracking on ubuntu 16.04 (nvidia jetson tx2). it works locally, but not remotely, producing the error in the title.